# Tomcat 7.0.20 and Java 6u30 how to protect against FREAK?

Tags: java, tomcat7

I am using Tomcat 7.0.20 and Java 6u30 and tries so many different configurations to disable unsecure ciphers but tomcat7 doesn't start. Actually it starts with errors.

**CASE 1:**

If I set connector like this:

```
    <Connector SSLEnabled="true" acceptCount="100" clientAuth="false"
    disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false"
    keystoreFile="XXXXXXXX" keystorePass="YYYYYYY" maxThreads="25"
    port="443" secure="true" 
    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" scheme="https" 
sslProtocol="TLS" sslProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"  />
```

I get this error in catalina file:

```
31/05/2017 07:11:00 org.apache.catalina.startup.SetAllPropertiesRule begin
AVISO: [SetAllPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Connector} Setting property 'sslProtocols' to 'TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2' did not find a matching property.
```

**CASE 2:**

If I set connector like this:

```
    <Connector SSLEnabled="true" acceptCount="100" clientAuth="false"
    disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false"
    keystoreFile="XXXXXXXX" keystorePass="YYYYYYY" maxThreads="25"
    port="443" secure="true" 
    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" scheme="https" 
sslProtocol="TLS"
sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1"
ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, 
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, 
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, 
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, 
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, 
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, 
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, 
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, 
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, 
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, 
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, 
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, 
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, 
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, 
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, 
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, 
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, 
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, 
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, 
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, 
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, 
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, 
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, 
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, 
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, 
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, 
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, 
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, 
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, 
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, 
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, 
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, 
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, 
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, 
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, 
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, 
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, 
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, 
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, 
TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSVF 
"
 />
```

I get this error in catalina file:

```
31/05/2017 06:59:44 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint setSocketOptions
GRAVE: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported ciphersuite TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.CipherSuite.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.CipherSuiteList.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.setEnabledCipherSuites(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.createSSLEngine(NioEndpoint.java:692)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.setSocketOptions(NioEndpoint.java:644)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Acceptor.run(NioEndpoint.java:789)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
31/05/2017 06:59:44 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint setSocketOptions
```

Comment: For the second solution, ciphers list might be whistespace sensitive, have you tried removing carriage returns for each cipher type ?

Comment: It isn't whitespace sensitive. The problem is that Java 6 is really old and ciphers are unsupported indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it leaving configuration like this:

```
    <Connector SSLEnabled="true" acceptCount="100" clientAuth="false"
    disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false"
    keystoreFile="XXXXXXXX" keystorePass="YYYYYYY" maxThreads="25"
    port="443" secure="true" 
    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" scheme="https" 
sslProtocol="TLS"  
sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1"
ciphers="TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"
/>
```

Java 6 seems not to support TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2 and just a few ciphers options were left to use.